# linker error with trying to create a direct x 11 window

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, linker, directx, directx-11

I have been trying to work with DirectX 11 for a while now, first I had Visual Studio 2010 with windows 7 and ran into the SDK bug when it's not creating the Direct3D device. So I uninstalled the SDK and installed Visual Studio 2012, and went with a whole new set of code to try and just create the window.

This is the error I get now when trying to build my project:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain@48 referenced in function "void __cdecl InitD3D(struct HWND__ *)" (?InitD3D@@YAXPAUHWND__@@@Z) C:\Users\thatguy\Documents\game dev\tutorial work\directx 11 tutorial\directx 11 tutorial\main.obj  directx 11 tutorial
```

This is the code I am trying to compile:

```
// include the basic windows header files and the Direct3D header files
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <d3dx11.h>
#include <d3dx10.h>

// include the Direct3D Library file
#pragma comment (lib, "d3d11.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "d3dx11.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "d3dx10.lib")

// global declarations
IDXGISwapChain *swapchain;             // the pointer to the swap chain interface
ID3D11Device *dev;                     // the pointer to our Direct3D device interface
ID3D11DeviceContext *devcon;           // the pointer to our Direct3D device context

// function prototypes
void InitD3D(HWND hWnd);    // sets up and initializes Direct3D
void CleanD3D(void);        // closes Direct3D and releases memory

// the WindowProc function prototype
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);


// the entry point for any Windows program
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                   int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hWnd;
    WNDCLASSEX wc;

    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wc.lpszClassName = "WindowClass";

    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    RECT wr = {0, 0, 800, 600};
    AdjustWindowRect(&wr, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, FALSE);

    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
                          "WindowClass",
                          "Our First Direct3D Program",
                          WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                          300,
                          300,
                          wr.right - wr.left,
                          wr.bottom - wr.top,
                          NULL,
                          NULL,
                          hInstance,
                          NULL);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);

    // set up and initialize Direct3D
    InitD3D(hWnd);

    // enter the main loop:

    MSG msg;

    while(TRUE)
    {
        if(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);

            if(msg.message == WM_QUIT)
                break;
        }
        else
        {
            // Run game code here
            // ...
            // ...
        }
    }

    // clean up DirectX and COM
    CleanD3D();

    return msg.wParam;
}


// this is the main message handler for the program
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(message)
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            {
                PostQuitMessage(0);
                return 0;
            } break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc (hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}


// this function initializes and prepares Direct3D for use
void InitD3D(HWND hWnd)
{
    // create a struct to hold information about the swap chain
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC scd;

    // clear out the struct for use
    ZeroMemory(&scd, sizeof(DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC));

    // fill the swap chain description struct
    scd.BufferCount = 1;                                    // one back buffer
    scd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;     // use 32-bit color
    scd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;      // how swap chain is to be used
    scd.OutputWindow = hWnd;                                // the window to be used
    scd.SampleDesc.Count = 4;                               // how many multisamples
    scd.Windowed = TRUE;                                    // windowed/full-screen mode

    // create a device, device context and swap chain using the information in the scd struct
    D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL,
                                  D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
                                  NULL,
                                  NULL,
                                  NULL,
                                  NULL,
                                  D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
                                  &scd,
                                  &swapchain,
                                  &dev,
                                  NULL,
                                  &devcon);
}


// this is the function that cleans up Direct3D and COM
void CleanD3D(void)
{
    // close and release all existing COM objects
    swapchain->Release();
    dev->Release();
    devcon->Release();
}
```

I have added the DirectX include directory and lib x64 and x86 directory and it still fails.

Comment: Enable /VERBOSE in the linker options and double check to make sure the right libraries are getting pulled in. Your directory settings may also be incorrect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add D3D11.lib in Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies.

Have you tried that ?

Comment: i tried that didn't make a difference still same exact error.

Comment: Are you compiling your app as 32bit or 64bit ?

Comment: that is a good question, I imagine I'm doing 32 bit as I've not changed anything from a default install of vs2012. but i honestly don't know how to switch between the two or tell if i am in 32 or 64 bit mode.

Comment: Just go to project properties -> Configuration manager and check if your platform is x64 or Win32. If it is 32bit , try adding a new platform for 64bit. ( I assume you are on a 64bit os)

Comment: That worked, thanks, apparently I need to run it in x64.. now to make sure the window creates... which it did so now i can actually program using directx 11!

Answer (score 0):

Dont use d3dx11.h anymore.
Call d3dclean after initd3d function.